# Transliterate The Paragraph from Indian regional language to English

Tags: python, google-api, text-mining, transliteration

I want translit([Transliteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transliteration)) paragraph from Hindi(any regional language) to English, using python.ex.

```
SOURCE: मेरा नाम मोहन है, और में एक गांव में रहता हूँ.
OUTPUT: Mera naam mohan hai, aur mein ek gaanv mein rahata hoon.
```

I have checked [google API](https://developers.google.com/transliterate/v1/getting_started) but it only supports javascript and HTML, where you type text using any source language and your text gets transliterated in your expected language. 
I want any rest-full cloud API which takes the text in any Indian regional language and transliterates in English, and that can be integrated with python.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you are currently working with describe any issues you are having with your current solution.

Comment: have a look at : https://github.com/sanskrit/sanskrit/blob/master/sanskrit/transliterate/sanscript.py

Comment: @DaImTo up till now I don't have anything. I am looking for a hint to proceed. I went through many articles but I didn't get anything related to this. That's why I posted this.

Comment: thanks, @DaImTo for your time and effort but I want Transliteration and the link that you have provided is for translation.

Comment: https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans this seems to work

Answer (score 0):

use [ai4bharat-transliteration 1.1.3](https://pypi.org/project/ai4bharat-transliteration/)

```
e = XlitEngine(src_script_type="indic", beam_width=10, rescore=False)
out = e.translit_word("नमस्ते", lang_code="hi", topk=5)
print(out)
# output: ['namaste', 'namastey', 'namasthe', 'namastay', 'namste']
```